# How can we write a user defined method is Objective C / Swift with completion handler

Tags: ios

Please I will be helpful if you provide an example in either language. Thanks in Advance . .

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
func searchForStuff(_argument:String,completion: (data: [String]?) -> Void){

}

self.searchForStuff("aString") { (data) in

}
```

Objective c

```
- (void)searchForStuff:(NSString*)astring finishBlock:(void (^)(NSArray* data))finishBlock;

[self searchForStuff:@"aString" finishBlock:^(NSArray *data) {

}];
```

Comment: Can write the syntax for calling this method as I am unknown to these language...

Comment: I updated my answer. Check out this great cheat sheet! http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/